# Which permission allows user to edit topics inside community in salesforce?

Tags: community, permissions, user, topics, salesforce-cms

I have created few topics as Community admin from content management and i want end users to only view topics inside community but not edit them. Which permission in salesforce restricts user from editing topics inside community page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot stop community user's from editing topics in community.  Kindly review [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpzRUAR/editing-user-topics-in-community) and vote for this feature.  You can remove 'Assign Topics' on profile if you still need, however users who do not have 'Assign Topics' permission cannot ask a question.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vinay, actually it's really helpful to know that its not possible so far. It would create a lot of mess if community user has access to edit/relate to posts which isn't owned by them.